# Issue with a chat app (React with hooks, NodeJS and SocketIO)

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, react-hooks

I'm doing an app with React/NodeJS/SocketIO, and there's a chat in it,
I think I did it wrong with sockets, so I'm asking for help,

I want to :
- 1st, get all messages stored in the server
- 2nd, see every new messages in live without reloading screen

**Here's a sum up of the component code**

```
// I create a hook "messages" with nothing in it, first
const [messages, setMessages] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    // I initialize the socket when the component is mounted
    socket.open();

    // I get, all messages already sent, from the server
    try {
      const dataMessages = await axios.get(
        `http://localhost:5000/api/chat/messages`
      );
      console.log("messages ", dataMessages);
      // I put all the messages in the hook "messages"
      setMessages(dataMessages.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

    // am I supposed to do something here with the socket "send message" ????

    // I stop the socket when the component is unmounted
    return () => {
      socket.close();
    };
  });

function sendMessage(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    socket.emit("send message", {data});
}

return (
    <input type="submit" onClick={sendMessage} />
)
```

**My main issue is that every second I got the log of the useEffect in the browser console, and i can't see the new messages I send**

Comment: Your example has a problem. You're using `await` inside a non async function.

Comment: @Mody yes it’s because I edited my original code to make it easier to read here don’t worry it’s all good in my editor, but i still got issues with sockets

Comment: You aren't rendering messages anywhere in your example. You are also closing the second on every update. I think think your socket logic should be in the useEffect handler.

Comment: i do a .map on messages, but i don't want to put too much code, the problem is about sockets implementation, i think i have to do a socket.on("chat message", ...) somewhere in the useffectbut don't know how exactly

Comment: Not in the useEffects at all. take out your socket stuff from useEffects. Also take out setMessages from useEffects. calling setMessages inside useEffects maybe do an infinite invocation. setMessages causes useEffects handler to get invoked and useEffects invokes setMessages etc

Comment: and what if I add a []as 2nd parameter of the useEffect to just do this one time when the component is mounted? because  I need to load messages stored in the server